# How can I create a folium.circle map with a time slider?

Tags: python, dictionary, time-series, folium

So I want to create an interactive map in Python similar to this one: https://bl.ocks.org/measrainsey/8190e298e0ef4eb950d0d6b91b32f2b4

My dataset looks like this.

```
+---------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+
|  date   |  city  | longitude | latitude |  data   |
+---------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+
| 2018/01 |  cityA |        10 |       10 |   50000 |
| 2018/01 |  cityB |        10 |       20 |  100000 |
| 2018/02 |  cityA |        10 |       10 |   60000 |
|     ... |    ... |       ... |      ... |     ... |
+---------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+
```

So the radius of each circle should be data. I tried to use `folium.circle` but I don't know how to add a timeslider.